# Set different scroll directions per device Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, keyboard, mouse, touchpad

I'm using a mouse keyboard combo as my main input device for my workstation.

The PC is also connected to my TV. When watching TV I like to use a cheap keyboard with touchpad. It does not have a brand, but on the back it says:

```
Wireless Keyboard
Model: ST-WK600
Art. nr.: IW.48.788
```

Since I am used to "natural scrolling" on my macbook, I would also like to use that for my touchpad.

However, I would like the mouse to behave like it does by default.

`gnome-control-center` only shows one setting for both mouse and touchpad. Is there a possibility to set scrolling behaviour per device?

[image: Gnome control center]

EDIT:
`hwinfo --short` output, cut down to relevant sections.

As you can see it includes my Logitech keyboard, MCE USB receiver and `unknown: Keyboard controller`, which I suspect is the keyboard touchpad combo, because there is no touchpad section and `/dev/input/mice` only lists one device.

```
keyboard:
/dev/input/event6    Logitech LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser
/dev/input/event17   MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb)
mouse:
/dev/input/mice      Logitech LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser
unknown:
                    FPU
                    DMA controller
                    PIC
                    Keyboard controller
                    Intel 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
                    Intel 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
                    Feature Integration Technology Inc. (Fintek) F71610A or F71612A Consumer Infrared Receiver/Transceiver
/dev/input/event2    P&E Micro Smart Control
                    ASUSTek BCM20702A0
```

EDIT 2: `xinput list` output. One of the `HLHB155` devices should be the touchpad.

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HLHB155 V1 10 27 01 Smart Control         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HLHB155 V1 10 27 01 Smart Control         id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb)            id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HLHB155 V1 10 27 01 Smart Control         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Media Center Ed. eHome Infrared Remote Transceiver (1934:5168)    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Eee PC WMI hotkeys                        id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HLHB155 V1 10 27 01 Smart Control         id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb)            id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 3):

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll false`
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll true`

If you receive *no such key*, run `dconf` and search for *scroll* or *scrolling*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this setting and also looked at dconf-editor. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I am suspecting that the keyboard with touchpad emulates a mouse or something. I updated my question with the hwinfo --short output.

Comment: is the touchpad listed by `xinput list`?

Comment: I updated my post with the `xinput list` output. I think the device is the `HLHB155`, because it disappears when I unplug the receiver

Comment: You can get more info for each ID, for example, `xinput -list-props 10`. See `xinput` manpage, maybe you can set "natural scrolling" property as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution, but here's a little python script I whipped up to toggle my display zoom & mouse direction, for switching between desk (mouse and 100%) & couch (trackpad & 200%).

Hope it's helpful.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
import sys

current = subprocess.check_output([
    'gsettings',
    'get',
    'org.gnome.desktop.interface',
    'scaling-factor'
])

if current == b'uint32 2\n':
    scale = 1
    natural = 'false'
elif current == b'uint32 1\n':
    scale = 2
    natural = 'true'
else:
    sys.exit('cannot determine current scale')

subprocess.call([
    'gsettings',
    'set',
    'org.gnome.desktop.interface',
    'scaling-factor',
    '%d' % (scale,)
])
subprocess.call([
    'gsettings',
    'set',
    'org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings',
    'overrides',
    "{'Gdk/WindowScalingFactor': <%d>}" % (scale,)
])
subprocess.call([
    'gsettings',
    'set',
    'org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse',
    'natural-scroll',
    natural
])
```